# return datetime in c# in class - Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'

Tags: c#, datetime

It is such that I have to have a date from tablen which has Date Hours,
I'll show something when I have an offer on the page which will be displayed on some dates,

I have tried to do like this

In my class **RabatHelper.cs**

```
public static long DatoFrom()
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    var RabatPriser = db.RabatPrisers.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Id == 1);
    if (RabatPriser != null)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64(RabatPriser.fromdato);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and in my packages should I have date forward to where I need it,

```
DateTime DatoFrom = new DateTime(RabatHelper.DatoFrom());
```

What it gives errors is this:

**Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'.**

```
if (RabatPriser != null)
{
return Convert.ToInt64(RabatPriser.fromdato);
}
return 0;
```

What I expect it to be able to do it's like it can do something like this here

```
DateTime DatoFrom = new DateTime(2015, 6, 24);
```

Comment: It is quite simple you can't cast from datetime to int64

Comment: @deathismyfriend Yes okay, but what should I write where I need to convert it ?, Seems just that I have tried many things, but maybe it's just ...

Comment: Howabout DateTime.Ticks

Comment: Or TimeSpan.Days, with TimeSpan computed as( datetime2-datatetime1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly convert a `DateTime` to a `long`. Why not keep your DateTime as is:

```
public static DateTime DatoFrom()
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    var RabatPriser = db.RabatPrisers.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Id == 1);
    if (RabatPriser != null)
    {
        return RabatPriser.fromdato;
    }
    //Instead of 0, return the minimum value?
    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh how delicious, I'm almost at the goal, but the fact is that I get errors here, `DateTime DatoFrom = new DateTime(RabatHelper.DatoFrom());` Error are: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'long'

Comment: You don't need to `new` it up now, just do `DateTime DateFrom = RabatHelper.DateFrom();`

Comment: Thanks for help, i hope u will giv me a +1 for my question